# How to handle two similar components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React. I have two components: TimePickerComponent and the TimeDurationPickerComponent.

The **TimePickerComponent** gets passed a TimeString(string) via props(only if initial data exists) and displays it like "08:00". Code:

```
class TimePickerComponent extends React.Component {
    _placeholder;
    _defaultTimeString;
    _timeString;
    _errorStatus;
    _classes;

    constructor({ placeholder, defaultTimeString, timeString, errorStatus, classes }) {
        super();
        this._placeholder = placeholder;
        this._defaultTimeString = defaultTimeString;
        this._timeString = timeString;
        this._errorStatus = errorStatus;
        this._classes = classes;
    }

    get Placeholder() {
        return this._placeholder;
    }

    get DefaultTimeString() {
        return this._defaultTimeString ? this._defaultTimeString : CONTROLS_CONSTANTS.DEFAULT_TIME_STRING;
    }

    get TimeString() {
        return this._timeString;
    }

    get ErrorStatus() {
        return this._errorStatus;
    }

    get Classes() {
        return this._classes;
    }

    render() {
        return <FormControl>
            <TextField error={this.ErrorStatus}
                label={this.Placeholder}
                defaultValue={this.TimeString ? this.TimeString : this.DefaultTimeString}
                className={this.Classes.layout}
                type="time"
                InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true
                }}
            />
        </FormControl>
    }
}

TimePickerComponent.propTypes = {
    placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    defaultTimeString: PropTypes.string,
    timeString: PropTypes.string,
    errorStatus: PropTypes.bool
}

export default withStyles(styles)(TimePickerComponent);
```

The **TimeDurationPickerComponent** gets passed a TimeInMinutes(number) via props. But the display is the same as of the TimePickerComponent("08:00"). Code:

```
class TimeDurationPickerComponent extends React.Component {
    _placeholder;
    _timeInMinutes;
    _classes;

    constructor({ placeholder, timeInMinutes, classes }) {
        super();
        this._placeholder = placeholder;
        this._timeInMinutes = timeInMinutes;
        this._classes = classes;
    }

    get Placeholder() {
        return this._placeholder;
    }

    get TimeInMinutes() {
        return this._timeInMinutes;
    }

    get Classes() {
        return this._classes;
    }

    get TimeString() {
        let timeFormat = CONTROLS_CONSTANTS.TIME_FORMATS.HOURS_MINUTES_COLON_SEPARATED;
        let duration = moment.duration({ minutes: this.TimeInMinutes });

        //https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463
        return moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format(timeFormat);
    }

    render() {
        return <TimePickerComponent
            placeholder={this.Placeholder}
            timeString={this.TimeString}
            classes={this.Classes}
        />
    }
}

TimeDurationPickerComponent.propTypes = {
    placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    timeInMinutes: PropTypes.number
}

export default TimeDurationPickerComponent;
```

To avoid code redundancy I reused my TimePickerComponent in the TimeDurationPickerComponent and just convert the TimeInMinutes in a TimeString and pass it down to the TimePickerComponent via props.

**My question now**: Is this a good practice how I solved this or should I use a HigherOrderComponent for that? Or should I use an inheritance approach for that? Which solution would be the best and why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: That said, your code seems fine to me (aside from the lack of props and state - see Dakota's answer) - in React it's idiomatic to prefer composition over inheritance, and a HOC is only really useful if you want to reuse the wrapper on multiple components.

Comment: Ok, so this form of questions should I post on the Code Review Stack Exchange site? 

Ok then my approach is totally fine, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, if you have working code that you want to *improve*, Code Review is the best place for it. If you can't make the code work in the first place, that's where Stack Overflow comes in :) It's definitely a bit of a blurry line between the two, though.

Comment: @JoeClay in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela: I wasn't aware of those guidelines - thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

What you've done here is probably fine. It could be done with a higher order component as well but a composition based approach like what you have won't have any performance issues and to be honest it's probably more readable than using an HOC.

On another note you should be using this.props and this.state to represent your class properties. They are build into React components and are what will  cause your component to automatically re-render upon change.

It also makes your code significantly more concise so for example you could reduce your second component down to something like this:

```
class TimeDurationPickerComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    createTimeString() {
        let timeFormat = CONTROLS_CONSTANTS.TIME_FORMATS.HOURS_MINUTES_COLON_SEPARATED;
        let duration = moment.duration({ minutes: this.props.TimeInMinutes });

        //https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463
        return moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format(timeFormat);
    }

    render() {
        return <TimePickerComponent
            placeholder={this.props.Placeholder}
            timeString={this.createTimeString()}
            classes={this.props.Classes}
        />
    }
}
```

Example of a component that uses flow:

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';

import './css/ToggleButton.css';

type Props = {
  handleClick: Function;
  label: string;
};

type LocalState = {
  active: bool,
};

class ToggleButton extends React.Component<Props, LocalState> {
  clickHandler: () => void;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      active: true,
    };

    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
    this.props.handleClick();
  }

  render() {
    const buttonStyle = this.state.active ? 'toggle-btn-active' : 'toggle-btn-inactive';
    return (
      <button
        className={`toggle-btn ${buttonStyle}`}
        onClick={this.clickHandler}
      >{this.props.label}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default ToggleButton;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know I could reduce the code of my components like you showed but then it isn't clear which props get passed to this component. When I define my constructor I can write all the props as parameters and I actually see all the props that are passed to this component. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yea thats why I use flow or typescript in all of my React apps. It lets you define the type of your props and state. I'll add an example in my answer it's really helpful if you want to spend some time setting it up. If you don't want to have to set up babel or the typescript transpiler flow has [comment types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/), but I would recommend using a transpiler because it makes the code cleaner.

Comment: I'm actually a big fan of typescript but we want to use some modules that don't support or don't work well with typescript. I think redux forms make some troubles or ImmutableJs.